# Жизненный цикл asp.net mvc страницы

Tags: asp.net

Может кто рассказать хоть что-нибудь про жизненный цикл ASP.NET MVC страницы?

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста сюда https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB+ASP.NET+MVC+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Так а там выдает жц всего приложения, а не странички. Разве не так?

Comment: В ответах я вижу именно "страниц".

Comment: так а тот вариант ответа не чисто для WebForms?

Comment: Я ASP.NET не занимаюсь ;) Но вот вам статья ASP.NET MVC vs. WebForms http://habrahabr.ru/post/47249/ в дополнение к гуглу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC не работает в терминах "страниц". Он работает в терминах "запрос", "маршрут", "контроллер", "действие", "результат", "вид".

Жизненный цикл страницы есть ASP.NET WebForms, но там с ASP.NET MVC почти ничего общего нет (кроме слова "ASP.NET" в названии).

Если не смущает английский, то для ASP.NET MVC 5 есть официальная статья с [PDF- схемой](http://i1.asp.net/media/4773381/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application.pdf) [Lifecycle of an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если хочется на русском, то цикл обработки запроса в MVC выглядит примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Честно взято с http://msdr.ru/9/. Схема нарисована для ASP.NET MVC 3, но практически вся актуальна.

Comment: А можно тогда поподробнее про запрос\маршрут\контроллер...

Comment: @habibti86 если коротко, то - маршрутизация, вызов действия, выполнение результата.

Comment: маловато, но все же спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: @habibti86 добавил поясняющую картинку

Comment: О, спасибо! Надо ознакомиться.